# Automatically checking the integrity of the SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to check the integrity of a SQL Server database? I have these developers (OK, me included) that constantly change objects in our database (views/functions/stored procs) and sometimes we change signatures of objects or drop objects and other objects become invalid/uncompilable. I would like to get some sort of a report/alert on what objects are broken preferably one that could be integrated with CruiseControl.NET. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is database unit tests that can then be executed through CruiseControl.NET. I recommend using tSQLt (http://tsqlt.org). RedGate also sells a nice GUI over the top of this product, but is not required to get the functionality that you need.
(http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/

Comment: I really like this tSQLt!

Answer (score 2):

Olla Hallengran provides an excellant way to check the Integrity of databases.
Please refer
http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html

Comment: This looked really interesting. I wonder what these scripts do underneath. As someone mentioned here, I am thinking I would need to re-compile all the objects which I really would hate to do.

Comment: Had a short read on the script, what i can say is it uses the power of built in DBCC commands. I recommended this script cause its widely used and also recognised

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is common - having multiple developers working on a database is problematic.

As far as I know, there's no easy way to check the integrity of the database objects in the way you mention - dependencies between stored procedures etc. are resolved at compile time, and the proc will return an error if that dependency is not valid at run time. You could re-compile all the procedures, functions, views etc. to flush out errors during a batch.

However, the problem is not that you need to check the integrity of your database, but rather that you don't have a process for avoiding problems with that integrity in the first place.

There are a number of solutions to this which minimize the problem; it kinda depends on your development set-up which way you go. The process is generally known as "continuous database integration".

Jeff Atwood provided an [overview](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html) ages ago, and an [update](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html) slightly less long ago (check out the links). Also look at the [Redgate tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-automation-pack/) - these make the process pretty painless.